# Single value in ng-repeat

Tags: php, angularjs, json

In my main ng-repeat div I have one div which should only contain a single matching value, what I tried now causes the same value to appear in every game because it is in the main ng repeat, what should I do instead of

```
<div class="row spacing10" ng-controller="latestfeed">
  <div class="col s1 offset-s11 time" ng-repeat="latest in latestfeed">{{ latest.minute }}</div>
</div>
```

to only get the minute of the event for the matching game?

HTML:

```
  <div id="live" class="container" ng-controller="games">
    <div ng-repeat="game in games">
      <div class="card-panel">
        <div class="row spacing10">
          <div class="col s11" ng-class="{'bold': game.firstscore > game.secondscore}">{{ game.first}}</div>
          <div class="col s1 customred" ng-class="{'customgreen': game.second > game.second}">{{ game.first|| 0 }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row spacing10" ng-controller="latestfeed">
          <div class="col s1 offset-s11 time" ng-repeat="latest in latestfeed">{{ latest.minute }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s11" ng-class="{'bold': game.second> game.first }">{{ game.second}}</div>
          <div class="col s1 customred" ng-class="{'customgreen': game.secondscore > game.firstscore }">{{ game.secondscore|| 0 }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('games', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://www.website.com/app/?data=games').success(function (data) {
    $scope.games= data;
  });
});

app.controller('latestfeed', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('https://www.website.com/app/?data=latestfeed').success(function (data) {
    $scope.latestfeed = data;
  });
});
```

PHP JSON queries:

```
games:
$sql->query('SELECT * FROM games WHERE dateofgame = :date');

latestfeed:
        $sql->query('SELECT * FROM event_items, feed, games
                     WHERE event_items.event_id = feed.event_id
                     AND feed.gamenumber = games.gamenumber
                     AND day = :date
                     ORDER BY feed.time DESC LIMIT 1');
```

games query output in short:

```
[{"gamenumber":6160,"},{"gamenumber":6161,"}]
```

latestfeed query output in short:

```
[{"event_id":4,"gamenumber":6160,"minute":40,"}]
```

HTML output:
One div contains gamenumber 6160 and one div contains gamenumber 6161, the minute 40 should only display in the first div in this case

Comment: It might help your question to show your current and expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope I made it a bit more clear

Comment: It doesn't.  Show current and expected output.  Either as HTML or maybe the SQL query itself.

Comment: I included the JSON outputs of the queries and a description of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with `ng-repeat="latest in latestfeed" ng-if="latest.gamenumber === game.gamenumber"`, I am new to Angular and did not know that this was possible